# Recommended way to handle query parameters (deeplink) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC + WebAPI website, most of the functionalities are implemented in JavaScript. When user navigates to my website, browser downloads html+js files first, then JavaScript sends AJAX to WebAPI to retrieve data from database, and presents data on page. Don't use too many ASP.NET MVC features here except binding, routing, WIF, etc.

Now I need to add query parameters support so user can share link with others. Basically I think I have two options to add deeplink support:

`1. Let server side C# code (MVC Controllers) to handle query parameters. 
This looks natural since web server receives GET request first, and ASP.NET maps query parameter to Controller function parameters, but since ultimately JavaScript code needs to use those parameters to compose and issue AJAX calls, so I need to figure out how to pass C# object to JavaScript code, looks a little tricky.`

`2. Let client side JavaScript code handles the query parameters.
In this way Controller will not aware of query parameters.`

Does anyone know what is the common and recommended way to handle query parameters in ASP.NET MVC application? like pros and cons? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of logic needs to be done with these query parameters? The answer to that would dictate the ideal choice.

Comment: @MikeMichaels Thanks for you reply. Parameters include like: time range, name, etc. Those are used to query database through WebAPI interface. JavaScript issues AJAX to WebAPI to query database.

Comment: @codewarrior It would be best to handle query params at controller level as you will query your DB from there

Comment: @AbdulSamad Querying DB is done in WebAPI, not MVC controller. Basically my current MVC controllers are trivial.

Comment: `...so I need to figure out how to pass C# object to JavaScript code`. WHAT do you mean by this? This is confusing. To issue an AJAX request you need to compose params via JS on client-side

Comment: @AbdulSamad because, Controller and C# code runs on server side, but my biz logic is implemented in JS on client side.

Comment: @codewarrior and why have you done so? Biz logic needs to be implemented on server-side. Please review your architecture asap. You will run into more problems as u move forward